# Rails 3.2.11 - server not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

i have just finished michael hartl's tutorial on rails 3.2 and decided to try an open source project and chose [this one](https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce/tree/1.4.2).
I have installed gems,updated bundler and when i try to start server , i get following error. how to resolve this issue ?

```
    ashku@ashku-Lenovo-G470:/media/ashku/New Volume/RoR/ecom$ rails s
/home/ashku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ror_ecommerce/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require': /media/ashku/New Volume/RoR/ecom/config/application.rb:1: Invalid char `\x01' in expression (SyntaxError)
/media/ashku/New Volume/RoR/ecom/config/application.rb:1: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
    from /home/ashku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ror_ecommerce/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ashku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ror_ecommerce/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/ashku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ror_ecommerce/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

on the top of your config/application.rb file.